# How can dataavailable events send data from a popup to a parent window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, events, popup

I'm trying to have a popup window notify its parent window that some data is available for the parent. The mechanism I'm using is the dataavailable event--the popup creates it and sends it to the parent. The parent listens for such an event, and the parent's event handler is called when the event occurs.

The problem is that I am trying to actually pass some data in the event. The data is not getting to the parent.

Here is the source code for the parent, test-parent.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test parent</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openPopup()
{
  window.open("test-popup.html", "popup", ['width=400', 'height=200']);
  window.addEventListener("dataavailable", onDataAvailableEvent, false);
}   

function onDataAvailableEvent(event)
{   
  alert("In onDataAvailableEvent(), " +
          "event.timeStamp '" + event.timeStamp + 
            "', event.eventType '" + event.eventType + "'");
}
</script>
</head>

<body> 
<input type="button" value="Open test-popup.html" onclick="openPopup()" />
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the source code for the popup, test-popup.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test popup</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onButtonClick()
{   
  var syntheticEvent = document.createEvent("Events");
  syntheticEvent.initEvent("dataavailable", true, false);
  syntheticEvent.eventType = "test-popup.html finished";
  window.opener.dispatchEvent(syntheticEvent);

  alert("Dispatched dataavailable event, " + 
          "syntheticEvent.timeStamp '" + syntheticEvent.timeStamp + 
            "', syntheticEvent.eventType '" + syntheticEvent.eventType + "'"");
}   
</script>
</head>  

<body>
<input type="button" value="Create dataavailable event" onclick="onButtonClick()" />
</body>
</html>
```

test-parent.html and test-popup.html both put up alert messages. The timestamps in both alert messages agree, so I am fairly certain that the event created by the popup is being received by the parent. The popup displays the correct value for syntheticEvent.eventType, but event.eventType in the parent is undefined.

The examples I have found on the web imply that it is possible to exchange data by putting it into a dataavailable event. **What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the `event.eventType` to `event.type` in **test-parent.html**...

```
function onDataAvailableEvent(event)
{   
  alert("In onDataAvailableEvent(), " +
          "event.timeStamp '" + event.timeStamp + 
            "', event.eventType '" + event.type + "'");
}
```

Then you will get the correct event type in your alert which is `dataavailable`